# Merging cell text using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem. The thing is that I need to merge text from cells into one other cell. It should look like this: The text from every four cells in the first column should be concatenated (preferably with spaces) and written into every single cell in the second column. I can't do this manually because the amount of data is too large. Does anyone have code, preferably VBA, that does this?

I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
Sub vba_concatenate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    
    Set SourceRange = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set TargetRange = Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each rng In SourceRange
        TargetRange.Cells(i).Value = rng.Value
        i = i + 1
        
        If i > TargetRange.Cells.Count Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sTxt As String
    Dim arrData, arrRes(), k As Integer
    Dim rngData As Range
    ' Load data from Column A
    Set rngData = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To 1)
    k = 1
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData) Step 4
        ' Cocate 4 cells
        For j = 0 To 3
            If i + j > UBound(arrData) Then Exit For
            sTxt = sTxt & " " & arrData(i + j, 1)
        Next j
        If Len(sTxt) Then
            arrRes(k, 1) = Mid(sTxt, 2)
            k = k + 1
        End If
        sTxt = ""
    Next i
    ' Write data to sheet
    rngData.Offset(0, 1).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this can be achieved with formulas alone:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(A:A,MROUND(ROW()+1,4)-3):INDEX(A:A,MROUND(ROW()+1,4)))
```

[image]

Another interpretation of your question:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4-3):INDEX(A:A,ROW()*4))
```

[image]